# Invalid jar exception when running job on hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, jar

I have created a jar file using apache ant but after using the command

$ hadoop jar HelloWorld.jar org.MaxTemperatureWithCombiner inputpath outputpath

It throws "Not a valid jar" exception.

This JAR works perfectly on another system, running the same version of Hadoop. So this is a configuration issue. I am now certain the jar is fine.

The 'hadoop jar' command is trying to search for the jar in the /home/myname which is my ubuntu home and not my dfs home which is something like '/user/myname' . so the jar is fine but it is unable to locate any jar.

Thus when i am in /home/myname/Desktop as my PWD. 
Then it says : Not a valid jar : /home/myname/Desktop/HelloWorld.jar

What are the possible solutions to this??

Comment: did you compare the jar on the "problem" system to the jar on the "working" system?  did you possibly corrupt the jar while transferring it?

Comment: Can you give more information? What is the exact error, did you download this jar or transfer it over from a new system, can your hadoop run other things like the pi example etc?

Comment: @AndrewMartin I tried running the example pi jar but it throws the same error.

Comment: @jtahlborn I transferred the jar using a USB drive so I don't think it is corrupted. Firstly I tried it with cygwin and got the same error. Then  I tried it with ubuntu.

Comment: I'm assuming you've Java correctly installed. Do you have your hadoop and java environment variables set? Have you got the Java set in your hadoop env file as well? You might find this link very useful: http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/

Comment: @AndrewMartin I have got JAVA_HOME in the hadoop-env.sh set

Comment: @user2672952: Check out the link in my previous comment. The tutorial is fantastic and should help you out.

Comment: I had gone through the tutorial during the setup. It was really helpful. I had followed every step.

Comment: @user2672952: Try to take a checksum for your jars in both the machines to be sure they are same.

Comment: I have done a thorough research on the problem and it seems its a path issue, the '$hadoop jar' command is trying to search for the jar in my Home folder instead of searching for it in the /usr/myname folder which is the home folder on the DFS ... Kindly help...

Comment: Thus when i am in /home/myname/Desktop as my PWD. 
Then it says : Not a valid jar : /home/myname/Desktop/HelloWorld.jar